# Network Physical address vs Virtual address

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, mac-address

It's possible to generate a network physical address by a virtual machine such that when real and virtual machine are connected to the network, nobody in the network can determine which one is a virtual address?

Comment: If they monitor the switch MAC table - they will always be able to see two MAC addresses on the physical port  so they would know a second device is attached either with a repeater or virtual machine

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44004888/781723, https://superuser.com/q/1209911.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 0):

Most devices will let you set an arbitrary MAC address for Ethernet (it varies greatly depending on the OS and setup), but there is nothing stopping you from cloning a MAC address - provided that the 2 devices are not in use at the same time.

Likewise you can change the MAC address of your physical adaptor to make it look like a virtual MAC address.

The first 3 parts of a MAC address normally give an indication of the vendor, so by making those the same, you would be able to achieve what you are trying to do.